# Не задается user__name

Tags: html, css, less

```css
user{
    display:flex;
}
.user__avatar{
width:57px;
    height:57px;}

  img {border-radius: 50%;}

.user__name{font-size: 1.06rem;
color: @black;
font-weight: 700 ;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" contect="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
   </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
      
          <div class="user">
         <div clsass="user__avatar">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/57/333" alt="">
          </div>
            <div classs="user__content">
             <div classs="user__name">Lewis<br>
             Nathaniel
             </div>
            <div classs="user__prof">UI &amp; UX Designer</div>                        
            </div>   
        </div>
          <div class="nav">2</div>
     
      
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
     
  
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Будьте внимателней. Браузер не будет догадываться, если в словах ошибки. А для читающих людей выставляйте отступы.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста смотри как ты верстаешь, у тебя `class` написано в среднем с 2-3 ошибками и из-за этого стили не работают, ибо на что им работать если ты класс не указал. И делай отступы, а то код становится нечитаем

```css
user {
    display:flex;
}

.user__avatar{
  width:57px;
  height:57px;
}

img {border-radius: 50%;}

.user__name {
  font-size: 1.06rem;
  color: @black;
  font-weight: 700 ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" contect="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
   </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
    
     <div class="container">
     
      <div class="header__inner">
      
          <div class="user">
          
            <div class="user__avatar">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/57/333" alt="">
          </div>
          
            <div class="user__content">
             <div class="user__name">Lewis<br>
               Nathaniel
             </div>
                <div class="user__prof">UI &amp; UX Designer</div>                       
            </div>  
            
        </div>
          <div class="nav">2</div>     
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </header>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что кроме уже указанного, стиль display: flex; для класса user тоже не сработает, ибо в селекторе нет точки перед именем класса в css.

Comment: все верно, не обратил внимание на css)